# DDL Script for installation anti-agile?

Tags: agile, ddl

I have heard a comment that using a DDL script for a database installation is anti-agile. Is this true and if so why? I have been looking online for my answers but couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact context, but I would say that DDL is very pro-agile as it supports a repeatable installation process. Maybe they meant that designing the entire database prior to development is anti-agile. I would tend to agree with this assessment, but there is nothing inherently anti-agile about DDL.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Supporting incremental updates is more convenient and also allows for repeatable builds.

This allows the database to be "refactored" or "evolve" - as changes to it are seen as a series of small adjustments to a base schema.

This allows for constant upgrades without having to manage database versioning explicitly yourself. The database is the source of its own version and the upgrade process only applies appropriate deltas if they are required.

There are several tools that can help with this - the best know being probably ruby on rails [active record migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). For java environments then [dbdeploy](http://code.google.com/p/dbdeploy/) is pretty good (I think there are versions of dbdeploy for .net and php environments too).